# Rocks installation, Disc not found

Tags: installation, dvd, rocks

I have a problem with rocks 6.2 installation from DVD. I am using jumbo (DVD). At the same begin when everything is starts my CDROM is opening and i got information "Disc Not Found". However installation is start from this CDROM (DVD). Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I dont know what was wrong but i burn new one DVD with rocks 6.1 and now everything works. Probably ma previous installation was crushed. However, when I create first time my DVD creating check sum was so long, second time it was mutch faster. Maybe here was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried both 6.2 and 6.1 and both behave the same. It ejects the DVD and complain that Rocks CD is not found. Here are the last three lines from the console before it ejects the DVD
   INFO    : trying to mount CD device /dev/sr0 on /mnt/stage2
   INFO    : device status is CDS_DISC_OK
   INFO    : ejecting /dev/sr0 ....

The ejecting happens immediately after the mounting. Anyone has any idea?

TIA,
EK

EDIT: 
My problem was to let it continue without specifying build or build ip= netmask= boot options. I assumed if I just press enter or wait for it to continue it is the same as typing build and pressing enter.

I hope someone will save the time I wasted trying to downloald all other versions and trying them one by one.

lol
EK